# Drop all rows of higher level multi-index if certain lower level index doesn't exist

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Suppose I have a DataFrame with two MultiIndex levels, such as:

```
     col1
A x     1
  y     2
B x     3
  y     4
C x     5
```

Now, if an index of the level 0 lacks the lower level index 'x' or 'y', I want to drop all rows associated with this index. So in this example I want to drop all rows of 'C' because there is no 'y' under 'C'. So the result should be:

```
     col1
A x     1
  y     2
B x     3
  y     4
```

Is there a nice/clean way to do this?

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
mask=df.unstack().isna().any(1)       
#created a mask to check if an index has a missing value or not
```

Finally:

```
df=df.loc[~df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(mask[mask].index)]
                                               #^getting index of where value is missing
                      #^excluding that value from the level 0
```

output of `df`:

```
        col1
A   x   1
    y   2
B   x   3
    y   4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `transform`

```
out = df[df.groupby(level=0)['col1'].transform('count')==2]
```